Need to host a simple landing page node app. Advice?
Just to start off, I'm a beginner when it comes to creating live projects so speak to me like a complete noob, I won't be offended.
I have a simple app with a landing page so the user can submit their info to receive a call back.
I utilized node to handle the submission with nodemailer transporter.
Since the app doesn't really need to retain any info, do I really need something like heroku or AWS? It's just submitting the info to an email.
If I don't need that, how would I go about making this application live? With a domain that was purchased from godaddy.
If what I am saying is not possible, and I absolutely need to host it on something like heroku, is heroku the best option? I don't expect a ton of traffic or submissions to the landing page.
BTW, I was unable to plug in the websites domain email (from godaddy) to the nodemailer. It failed no matter what settings I used.
If a GitHub repo will help, here it is below.
https://github.com/rudy35hernandez/Liberty-Gold

Not directly related, but you don't need to commit your node_modules on the repo. It's a waste of time and space because in your packages.json file your dependencies are listed, so they can be downloaded by people locally. When people clone a repo, they usually read a readme file to follow instructions or simply just download packages using "npm install" (or similiar). They don't need to get the packages from your repo.

https://www.reddit.com/r/node/comments/169fb07/what_is_the_best_place_to_host_a_nodejs_app_in/

@MH thanks for the advice. As I said in my OP i am very new to development. To achieve this, do I just add the node_modules to my .ignore folder?

Yes, except that you would need to delete them first and commit those changes. Next, add node_modules to gitignore in another commit. Then you could re install them.

Since it is small project, you don't need to use AWS, it will be expensive if you are using AWS. You can just find shared hosting, I personally use Asphostportal and I can recommend their service.
